# Regular expression remove some links

Tags: html, regex

i need a regular expression to strip html  tags for some links

example

```html
<a href="falanfilan.com" target="_blank"> link </a>

<a href="sample.com" target="_blank"> fasafiso </a>
```

should be converted to

```html
<a href="falanfilan.com" target="_blank"> link </a>

fasafiso
```

Comment: So, if the link has `href="falanfilan.com"` in it, then don't do anything, otherwise remove the anchor tag?

Comment: you should rely specify the idea behind the replacement, because currently it looks like a simple search for `"<a href="sample.com" target="_blank"> fasafiso </a>"` to be replaced by `"fasafiso"` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your programming language, you could come up with sth. like:

```
~<a href="sample\.com" [^>]*>(.*?)</a>~
# delimiter ~
# look for <a, everything that is not > and >
# capture everything lazily in a group
# look for a closing tag
# delimiter ~
```

In your example, group 1 would hold `fasafiso` and could be replaced/insert via the group `$1`.
See a demo for this [approach on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eK4jH7/).

### Hint:

This is just a quick-and-dirty solution (e.g. for text editors). If this is getting more complicated, consider using a parser instead.

Comment: i want to just fasafiso

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to replace all links whose target is `sample.com` by their content :

match `<a[^>]*href="sample.com"[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>`
replace by `\1`

For example with sed :

```
sed 's/<a[^>]*href="sample.com"[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>/\1/'
```

Please also keep in mind that if your requirements are complex enough you should instead be using an HTML parser.